# Параллельная замена значений столбцов sql

Tags: sql, update

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как одним запросов в строках, где thursday заменить значение на friday, а в строках friday значение на thurdsday?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью кейсов:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET day = CASE WHEN day = 'friday' THEN 'thursday' 
               WHEN day = 'thursday' THEN 'friday' END
WHERE day IN ('friday','thursday')
```